# Convert AudioBuffer from JavaScript (Fload32Array) to C# (ByteArray)

Tags: javascript, c#, audio, type-conversion, microphone

I am trying to receive audio stream from microphone from browser and send it to MS Cognitive Speech Services.

I use JavaScript like below in order to get audio stream buffer.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then((mic) => {
    var mediaStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(mic);

    var recorder = null;
    if (audioContext.createScriptProcessor) {
        recorder = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(44100, 512, 1);
    } else {
        recorder = audioContext.createJavaScriptNode(44100, 512, 1);
    }

    recorder.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
        _dotNetAudio.sendAudioBuffer(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0));
    }

    mediaStream.connect(recorder);
    recorder.connect(audioContext.destination);

    sendSuccessMessage(mic.id);
})
.catch((e) => {
    sendErrorMessage(e.message);
});
```

The method _dotNetAudio.sendAudioBuffer invokes C# method to service stream data.

```
    [JSInvokable]
    public Task OnAudioBufferReceived(object audioBuffer)
    {
        if(audioBuffer == null) return Task.CompletedTask;

        if (audioBuffer is JsonElement)
        {

            double[] doubleArray = ((JsonElement)audioBuffer).EnumerateObject().Select(x => x.Value.GetDouble()).ToArray();

            **byte[] bytesArray = doubleArray;**

            AudioBufferReceived?.Invoke(this, bytesArray);
        }
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

But I have no idea how to convert received microphone data from JavaScript (Fload32Array type / double[]) to byte[]. It is required for provide data for PushAudioInputStream (Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio).

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The C# equivalent of a `Float32Array` is `float[] `. Try using that instead of `object`.

Comment: Ok, but how to convert float[] to byte[]? I got value of float array like { 9.909091209, -0.004444, 0.00133, 5.33333... } .

Comment: Like this: `byte[] bytesArray = new byte[floatArray.Length * sizeof(float)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(floatArray, 0, bytesArray, 0, bytesArray.Length);`

Comment: Looks like there is good to convert stream data. But speech recognition does not work. Maybe there is something wrong with stream conversion. The method 'Write(byte[])' of the PushAudioInputStream description: "Writes the audio data specified by making an internal copy of the data. Note: The dataBuffer should not contain any audio header.". Is the InputBuffer contain audio header?